# Using Rust and the match statement how can I assign a TcpListener?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust in my spare time, and I'm having trouble finding the answer to this problem. The code below which has been slightly modified appeared on Stack-O in answer to another question.I have split lines 9 and 14 for my testing purposes, but that is not essential.

What I would like to do is to use the match statement to assign the variable from line 8/9, or from lines 8/9 and 14 combined would also be suitable.

Could someone please show me how to this using the match statement?

```
001  use std::cell::Cell;
002  use std::rt::io::{Writer, Listener, Acceptor};
003  use std::rt::io::net::tcp::TcpListener;
004  use std::rt::io::net::ip::{SocketAddr, Ipv4Addr};
005
006  fn main() {
007
008      let o_listener =  TcpListener::bind(
009        SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 9123}).listen();   
010
011      print ("Listener opened : ");
012      std::io::stdin().read_line();      
013
014      let mut o_acceptor = o_listener.unwrap();
015
016      println("listener is ready");
017      loop {
018          let stream = Cell::new(o_acceptor.accept().unwrap());
019          do spawn {
020              let mut stream = stream.take();
021              stream.write(bytes!("Hello World\r\n"));
022          }
023      }
024  }
```

Example Only: For example using something like the following, but obviously for the above problem:

```
extern mod sqlite;

fn db() {

    let database = match sqlite::open("test.db") {
        Ok(result) => result,
        Err(error) => {
            println(fmt!("Error opening test.db: %?", error));
            return;
        }
    };
```

Edited Update : 12 hours after posting question *******

I'm using 0.8 on Win8

The following is an example of the problem that I would very-much like a solution to :

```
001  use std::cell::Cell;
002  use std::rt::io::{Writer, Listener, Acceptor};
003  use std::rt::io::net::tcp::TcpListener;
004  use std::rt::io::net::ip::{SocketAddr, Ipv4Addr};
005
006  fn main() {
007  
008  //   This works :
009  //   let o_listener =  TcpListener::bind(
010  //      SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 9123}).listen();
011
012  // This doesn't work, and results in compile errors below: 
013  let o_listener =  match TcpListener::bind(
014    SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 9123}).listen() {
015        Some(result) => result,
016        None => fail!("Failed to open listener")
017    };
018
019  // this works in combination with lines 9/10    
020  let mut o_acceptor = match o_listener {
021      Some(result) => result,
022      None => fail!("Failed to open acceptor.")
023  };
```

The attempt to compile the above results in (part only) :

```
test_tcp_008.rs:20:8: 20:20 error: mismatched types: expected `std::rt::io::net:
:tcp::TcpAcceptor` but found `std::option::Option<<V21>>` (expected struct std::
rt::io::net::tcp::TcpAcceptor but found enum std::option::Option)
test_tcp_008.rs:20         Some(result) => result,
```

This also does not work (compile error) :

```
fn main() {
    let mut o_acceptor = match TcpListener::bind(
      SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 9123})
      .listen().unwrap() {
          Some(result) => result,
          None => fail!("Failed to open Listener/Acceptor.")
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this: (I haven't tried to compile this yet, so it might need a few changes)

```
let o_acceptor = match o_listener {
    Some(listener) => listener,
    None => fail!("Failed to open listener.")
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric. However, while it "works", it doesn't solve the problem, because if Listener does not bind, I have a problem. That's why I said either lines 8 and 9 of my example or 8/9 and 14 combined. Perhaps in reality it needs to be only 8/9, and using Some/None doesn't appear to work for that. Thanks for your example and not telling me to RT7M.

Comment: @BrianOh, your question is not clear: if `bind` doesn't work then it returns `None`. What exactly do you want to do when this happens?

Comment: I attempted to use "match" with lines 8/9 of my example, but I couldn't get it to work. Perhaps I should have concentrated on that point, but as I said, I am trying to learn, so I'm a beginner with Rust. I'm using 0.8 on win8, and when I attempt "match" on 8/9, I get "test_tcp_008.rs:15:8: 15:20 error: mismatched types: expected `std::rt::io::net:
:tcp::TcpAcceptor` but found `std::option::Option<<V21>>` (expected struct std::
rt::io::net::tcp::TcpAcceptor but found enum std::option::Option)
test_tcp_008.rs:15         Some(result) => result," (part only). What should I do?

Comment: I have expanded my question with additional examples.

Comment: An update for those of us just stumbling on this now: panic! is now used in place of fail!

Answer (score 1):

The [return type of `bind`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/rt/io/net/tcp/struct.TcpListener.html) is `Option<TcpListener>`, that is, there is only one "layer" of Options that you need to unwrap. `match`ing twice, or `match`ing and calling `.unwrap()` (which is `Option<T> -> T`), is effectively assuming that the type is `Option<Option<TcpListener>>`. Hence, the following should work:

```
fn main() {
    let o_acceptor = TcpListener::bind(
       SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 9123}).listen();

    print ("Listener opened : ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line();

    match o_acceptor {
        Some(_) => println("listener is ready"),
        None => println("listener failed to bind")
    }

    println("possibly starting requests");

    match o_acceptor {
        // this will need to be `Some(ref acpt)` or possibly 
        // `Some(ref mut acpt)` to avoid moving `o_acceptor`
        // if you wish to use it later.
        Some(acpt) => {
            let mut acpt = acpt;
            loop {
                let stream = Cell::new(acpt.accept().unwrap());
                do spawn {
                    let mut stream = stream.take();
                    stream.write(bytes!("Hello World\r\n"));
                }
            }
        }
        None => {
            println("cannot accept because listener failed to bind");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I still have one "small" problem. How do I continue rather than fail? IE: instead of "None => fail!("Failed to open listener.")". I don't want to fail. I want to set a variable (bool) to false to indicate that we're not "connected" to port. Can that be solved?

Comment: @BrianOh, what would the value of `o_acceptor` be when that variable is `false`?

Comment: Well, dbaupp, with respect, I don't really know what o_acceptor would be in that situation. The bool was my desperate and temporary attempt to get something working. Strictly speaking, I would not create another variable that is redundant. In another language I'd test for nil or null and know that it hasn't been assigned. I've searched high and low on this to find an example without success. The only slightly-comparable examples that I've seen simply fail. There's a bit to learn with Rust, and I'd prefer to get something working and acquire the knowledge gradually with some help.

Comment: @BrianOh, this is actually the perfect place for `Option` as it is: option essentially wraps the "is this valid" boolean into the type itself, because it is defined to be `enum Option<T> { None, Some(T) }`, that is, it either holds nothing (`None`, the error state), or it holds a single value of type `T` (`Some(T)`, the success state). So, in this case, you'd just avoid unwrapping totally, and perform the `match` where you'd test for null in another language. (In this case, `Option` is essentially acting like a nullable pointer.) Note that you still need to unwrap the `Some` variant to use it.

Comment: Thanks dbaupp. Without being flippant, I'll attempt to get to know all of that. Sometimes I think it's best to just be shown how it's done, and eventually, it all comes together. Hopefully, in a few months I'll look back and see how thick I was. However I think I've put in enough hard-yards on this, and need to know the answer. Perhaps you have answered it, but my test-program is still not working. A picture is a thousand words, and an example is also.

Comment: @BrianOh, the only reason I haven't given an example (etc) is because I'm not sure what you want to do (i.e. the big picture, not the details of detecting a failure-to-bind, since the answer to "how do I implement *x*? [which leads to *y*]" and "what's the correct way to implement *y*?" is sometimes different), so I can't give a useful one. What do you want to happen when you can't open the stream? In broad terms, that logic goes in the `None` branch of the match.

Comment: In either case Done/None, I want the program to continue, and I need to know whether the "connection" has been made or not. In another language I would leave the connection object to nil/null if unsuccessful, and treat that as a boolean to know whether the connection has been made. I can't give an example because I don't know how "it" is done. You say that you can't give an example because I can't show what I want done. I don't want the "None" to fail, but I need to know whether the "connection" has been made. I can then say effectively "if connected then ...." (etc.), in subsequent code.

Comment: @BrianOh, example added.

Comment: @BrianOh You see, matching *is* the branching that you want; that way you get the detection of whether it worked and the using of it in one step—thus syntactically avoiding a common class of bug (that is, dereferencing null pointers or using junk data and only finding out later).

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. I think this basically brings us back to Eric's answer, and my reply to that solution. I need to detect the failure to bind, and to not fail, but continue knowing whether or not the bind succeeded. The amended example just fails non-gracefully if the bind does not succeed.

Comment: @BrianOh, my amended example doesn't fail at all: the `None =>  println("listener failed to bind")` branch is an example of detecting the failure-to-bind, and execution continues after that. The knowledge about whether the bind failed or not is embodied in the value of `o_acceptor`: if it is `None` then the bind failed, if it is `Some(<some object>)` then the bind succeeded.

Comment: @BrianOh, I hate to just RTFM you, but have you [read the tutorial section on `enum`s](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html#enums)? (`Option` is an enum, defined as I wrote above.)

Comment: Well, sorry to disappoint you dbaupp, but failure to bind on 0.8 Win8, using your example results in : "task <unnamed> failed at 'assertion failed: `(left == right) && (right == left)` (left:`0i32`, right: `-4092i32`)', C:\bot\slave\dist2-win\build\src\libstd\rt\
uv\net.rs:302

Comment: I probably should advise, in case there is a better way than this. I had to make a slight change to the example by dbaupp by adding the 2nd line in the following, to make the "variable" "acpt" a "mut" :        "Some(acpt) => {
     let mut acpt = acpt;"

Comment: @BrianOh, well that's the first time you've said *what* the failure is; in any case, I think that's a bug, [it's even as "this can fail" in the source](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/0.8/src/libstd/rt/uv/net.rs#L301-L302), so the only way to fix it is to upgrade your Rust to the master branch. :( (Oh, and yes, I'd forgotten about that mutability.)

Comment: Well, thanks for clarifying. The reason that I didn't explain that the failure was essentially something that couldn't be corrected in an application program, was that I did not know that. I presumed that it was something that had to be rectified by applying the "match" to the bind result, and I presumed that I was doing something wrong. I had been advised that there was a bug, but I didn't know that the bug prevented the match on the bind from working. I was told to RTFM, which I did, and I couldn't find a solution, so I made this post. I presume that 0.9 will fix this.

Comment: @BrianOh, out of curiosity, do you even hang out in the Rust IRC channel? They tend to be a pretty helpful bunch, and sometimes having more real-time feedback can help. There's a link to a web client for the IRC channel on rust-lang.org, which makes it pretty quick to get started.